# Devise with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How do I setup devise with more than one model?
I've already tried using rolify and cancan to setup separate roles in my database, but each role has a different way to authenticate themselves to login. For example, a student will have a student_number, and a lecturer will have a username but no student_number. 
Also there is a bunch of other attributes a lecturer won't have that a student will and vice versa.

I'm new to rails 4.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate with more than one model, with models that have some set of overlapping attributes?

Comment: Hey, Yeah there's like one similar attribute, but they're completely different models. I'm thinking of solving it with inheritance but the only issue is authentication. How would I authenticate both models with completely different attributes, student_number and username. I get stuck when I think that if I inherit from User (that has both student_number and username), one of these will be left blank on registration and devise may complain about it...

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models

Comment: @acts_as_geek If I try that, and my second model has username instead of email for example. And I add username to config.authentication_keys (config.authentication_keys = [:email, :username]). would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like classes and inheritance can come handy in this case.
What about defining a User mode and the let Student and Lecturer inherit from that class?

```
class Student < User
  # student's peculiar attributes
end

class Lecturer < User
  # lecturer's peculiar attributes
end
```

Then you can have two separate controllers and corresponding views. The the login page might have two links to the proper login pages.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great solution, but how would I get devise to authenticate students with their student_number and lecturers with their username? I ask this because, a lecturer won't have a student_number and thus I can't leave it empty in the database...

Comment: If students don't have a username, you can authenticate users through the username field and in the case of students set it by default to their student number.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using a User model and a "has_one" Profile model attached to User, all users log in using the same table but devise load another data saved in Profile.

Other option is use just User model and left student_number empty when the user is not an student.